# Usage of "llevar a trabajar" vs "llevar al trabajo"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I have found this example (which is counterintuitive, in my opinion) in *"Uso de la gramática española. Elemental", Francisca Castro, Edelsa 2000*:

> Yo no llevo el coche a trabajar normalmente.

Why do they use "a trabajar" instead of "al trabajo"? Which dictionary item or grammar topic should I study to understand this better?

I have found other examples of both usages in the Internet:

**llevar a trabajar**: 54,300 results in Google, for example:

- Yo no tengo ningún transporte público que me pueda llevar a trabajar.
- A su parecer, el trabajo del Premio Nacional de Ciencias nos puede llevar a trabajar en base a la excelencia de los alimentos.
- Simple y rápido de hacer, para cualquier tipo de pelo, para llevar a trabajar, a clase, para ir a tomar algo, para ir a la playa.

**llevar al trabajo**: 598,000 results in Google, for example:

- Necesito recetas sencillas de comida para llevar al trabajo.
- Me llevaré a la niña al trabajo; no tengo con quién dejarla.
- Este himno nos enseña como la lealtad nos puede llevar al trabajo en equipo y a la solución de problemas.

Is there any difference between the usage of "llevar a trabajar" and "llevar al trabajo"? Perhaps, regional differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### About your first example:

In my opinion the first example you show, is not only counter-intuitive, but also ambiguous:

> *Yo no llevo el coche a trabajar normalmente*.

- Doesn't he usually drive by car when commuting to work?
- Doesn't he usually takes his car to make it work (for example the owner of a taxi car).

When talking about carrying something to work, I've always used and heard: `llevar al trabajo`.

> *Llevar al trabajo*  →  Take or hold someone or something when going to work.
>   *Llevar a trabajar*  →  Take someone or something to make it work.

---

### About the examples you found with google:

Regarding the first one, I should say instead:

- *Yo no tengo ningún transporte público que me pueda llevar **al trabajo***

The second one is completely right, I give you how I should translate it:

- *A su parecer, el trabajo del Premio Nacional de Ciencias nos puede llevar a trabajar en base a la excelencia de los alimentos*.
- According to him, the work of the National Sciences Award can lead us to work based on the excelence of food.

About the third one, I should say instead:

- *Simple y rápido de hacer, para cualquier tipo de pelo, para llevar **al trabajo**, a clase, para ir a tomar algo, para ir a la playa*.

Comment: +1 for correctness.